# Can't properly align my CSS menu

Tags: css, navigation, alignment

I'm trying to learn CSS/HTML at the moment so sorry if there is a really obvious solution to this. I'm just using this to practice what I've learnt at the moment, but it keeps going wrong.

After literally hours of messing around with my code, I've finally got my navigation bar to align to the right, without messing everything else up. However it now won't sit in my "header" div. My basic structure is a header div, and within that a div for the logo (aligned to the left), and a div for the navigation menu (aligned to the right).

However after finally getting them aligned correctly, I can't seem to get my menu div in the right place. Here is a picture illustrating what I mean:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ot5ls.png

I have temporarily changed the colour of my "header" div to black, to better illustrate my problem. As you can see, my menu is underneath the header div, and also slightly to the right?

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>T5</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body id="home_p">

<div id="header">

<div id="logo">
</div>

<div id="menu">

<ul id="nav">
<li id="home"><a href="#"></a></li>
<li id="about"><a href="#"></a></li>
<li id="portfolio"><a href="#"></a></li>
<li id="contact"><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>

</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
body
/* T5 */
{background-color:#fff8d3; font-size:100%;}

body#home_p #home{background:url('home.gif') 0 -45px;}
body#about_p #about{background:url('about.gif') 0 -45px;}
body#portfolio_p #about{background:url('portfolio.gif') 0 -45px;}
body#contact_p #about{background:url('contact.gif') 0 -45px;}

#header {
background-color:#000000;
height:45px;
width:1200px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:90px;
}

#logo {
background-image('logo.gif');
height:45px;
width:181px;
}


#menu {
width:328px;
float:right;
}

#nav
{position:absolute;}

#nav ul{
display: inline;
}


#nav li{
height:45px;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
list-style:none;
position:absolute;
right:0px;
top:0px;
display:inline;
float:right;
}

#nav a
{height:45px;
display:block;
}


#home{left:0x; width:62px;}
#home{background:url('home.gif') 0 0;}
#home a:hover{background: url('home.gif') 0 -45px;}

#about{left:62px;width:65px;}
#about{background:url('about.gif') 0 0;}
#about a:hover{background: url('about.gif') 0 -45px;}

#portfolio{left:147px;width:98px;}
#portfolio{background:url('portfolio.gif') 0 0;}
#portfolio a:hover{background: url('portfolio.gif') 0 -45px;}

#contact{left:265px;width:83px;}
#contact{background:url('contact.gif') 0 0;}
#contact a:hover{background: url('contact.gif') 0 -45px;}
```

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS:

```
body
{
    background-color: #fff8d3;
    min-width: 600px;
}

body#home_p #home, body#about_p #about, body#portfolio_p #about, body#contact_p #about
{
    background-position: 0 -45px !important;
}

#header
{
    background-color: black;
    height: 45px;
    width: 90%;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 90px;
}

#logo
{
    background-image: url('logo.gif');
    background-color: #fff8d3;
    height: 45px;
    width: 181px;
}

#nav
{
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#nav li
{
    height: 45px;
    margin: 0 -2px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
}

#nav li:hover
{   
    background-position: 0 -45px;
}

#nav a
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: abosolute;
    display: block;
}


#home
{
    width: 62px;
    background-image: url('home.gif');
}

#about
{
    width: 65px;
    background-image: url('about.gif');
}

#portfolio
{
    width: 98px;
    background-image: url('portfolio.gif');
}

#contact
{
    width: 83px;
    background-image: url('contact.gif');
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>T5</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body id="home_p">
        <div id="header">
            <!-- The floating elements have to go before the main content, or they will appear below. -->
            <ul id="nav">
                <li id="home" title="Home"><a href="javascript:void();"></a></li>
                <li id="about" title="About"><a href="javascript:void();"></a></li>
                <li id="portfolio" title="Portfolio"><a href="javascript:void();"></a></li>
                <li id="contact" title="Contact"><a href="javascript:void();"></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="logo"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is perfect but I don't really understand all the changes!

Comment: After going over it all slowly, and reading about positioning again, I think I understand now. At first I didn't understand how the menu could go before the logo in the HTML! But now I understand positioning a bit more. Thanks!

Comment: I made a lot of other small improvements, too.  You had a lot of typos, code that wasn't doing anything, code that could be condensed, etc.  Be sure to compare it to your previous code, too.

Answer (score 0):

By setting `position:absolute` on *#nav* but not giving it coordinates (`left/top`), it falls somewhere else. Add a border to it and you'll see. But let's put that aside:

- You don't need the absolute position on the menu items. Set each to `float:left` with a margin
- Set `position:relative` on *#header*, then anchor *#nav* to the top right with `position:absolute`
- Since every link shares the same hover state, declare `a:hover` only once changing the background-position
- Use an accessible image replacement method, keep the actual text in your HTML

Here's a scaffold for you to build on: http://jsfiddle.net/Pz3Q3/

I strongly recommend you to read this: http://na.isobar.com/standards/

Comment: I think I tried to do too much too soon! Have read more now about positioning and I think I understand it better now. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, it's because he put the floating elements after the non-floating elements.  Simply setting an element to absolute positioning will never change its current position, only its dimensions and how it affects the positions of siblings.

Comment: @Zenexer "somewhere else" -> not where intended (in this case, the normal flow position).

Answer (score 0):

The width you are setting on your #menu is causing havoc throughout your CSS.  Your "#nav ul" isn't doing anything.  But ultimately the problem is that your #logo needs to have a float: left;

All the absolute positioning is unnecessary.  Use this:

```
#logo { 
  background-image('logo.gif'); 
  height:45px; 
  width:181px; 
  float: left;
} 

#menu { 
  float: right;
} 

#nav li{ 
  list-style:none; 
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried your suggestion but now I can't even see the menu?

Comment: Actually it's ok now, I got it from another response too. Thanks :)